Proving a $\sigma(E',E)$-compactness, where $E$ is only a vector space.
Let $(E, \geq)$ be a real ordered vector space and $U$ a nonempty subspace of $E$.
A functional $I:E\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be $U$-additive if $I(x + u) = I(x) + I(u)$ for all $x \in E$ and all $u \in U$. We denote by $E'$ the set of all linear functionals on $E$ (not necessarily the topological dual), and if $f \in E'$ we write $f(x)$ or $\langle x, f \rangle$ indifferently.
Assume $I$ is sublinear, i.e., $I(x+y)\leq I(x)+I(y)$ and $I(ax)= aI(x)$ for all $a\in[0,1]$, and that $I$ is $U$-additive.
Question: Consider the set $K\subset E'$ with
$$
K = \{ f \in E : f(x) \leq I(x) \, \text{for all} \, x \in E \, \text{and} \, f(u) = I(u) \, \text{for all} \, u \in U \}.
$$
Clearly, $K$ is convex. If $x \geq 0$, then $-x \leq 0$, $f(-x) \leq I(-x) \leq 0$, and $f(x) \geq 0$. Thus, $K$ consists of positive linear functionals.
Moreover, $(f_n)\to f$ in $\sigma(E',E)$ if and only if $(f_n(x))\to f(x)$ for all $x\in E$. From this it is easy to see that $K$ is closed in $\sigma(E',E)$.
How to show that $K$ is $\sigma(E',E)$-compact?   This compactness is asserted without proof  on page 275 of this article.

Isn't $(E',\sigma(E',E))$ ($E'$ denoting the algebraic dual of $E$) a complete (Hausdorff) TVS. You know that K is $\sigma(E',E)$-closed so to proof that it is $\sigma(E',E)$-compact you need to show that $K$ is totally bounded.

As you can see the paper isnt written by mathemacians, statements theirin are so vague. There is lack of precision

Maybe I'm missing something, but is this not just an application of Banach–Alaoglu? As you note $K$ is closed, you just need to verify $K$ is bounded, which follows if you assume some bound on $I$. (Also $E^{\prime}$ is all $\textbf{continuous}$ linear functionals on $E$)

@Se7venn $E'$ supposed to be the algebraic dual. Also to apply Banach–Alaoglu  on need some topology on $E$.

My mistake! Look at the original paper they reference, the exposition there is perhaps  better. In that paper, they end up showing that functionals are continuous by showing that they are positive. Then you proceed by B-A. Also, the paper specifies $E$ is equipped with the topology $\tau$, no?

The fact positive operators are continuous is true on spaces endowed with the  sup-norm. I don't know if this true in general
